# Import key-value text file using PowerQuery

Tags: microsoft-excel, power-query

I need to import some large log files from a firewall into Excel.
A truncated version (there are nearly 100 pairs per record) looks like this:

```
"itime=1682240966","date=""2023-04-23""","time=""18:39:26""","devid=""FG101FTK21000840""","vd=""root""","type=""traffic""","subtype=""forward"""
"itime=1682240960","date=""2023-04-23""","time=""18:39:20""","devid=""FG101FTK21000840""","vd=""root""","type=""traffic""","subtype=""forward"""
```

Out of the box, PowerQuery makes a fair stab at importing these, creating text columns of key-value pairs:

```
   Column1       |     Column2
itime=1682240960 | date="2023-04-23" ... etc
```

A simple transform/extract based on separators gets me the data.

If only it were that easy.

For some bizarre reason, known only to Fortinet the export format from the firewall is not consistent and no two CSVs are exactly the same which totally messes with the import based on what data is expected to be in what column.

Now, I could write a script in VBA or take it outside and do it in Python but I can't help thinking that there must be a more elegant way of doing this from within Excel / PowerQuery

Comment: What is "not consistent" in the CSV's that you are downloading. If that can be answered then a process could be created (regardless if it is power query, formula or vba, etc) to account for that. Otherwise, the only alternative is manual manipulation.

Comment: @gns100 I'm thinking that as well. I think what's happening (and I have a support job logged with the vendor) is that if a column(s) in the extract contains no data, then it is omitted. Trouble is there is no way of determining which column or columns are going to be missing without examining the thing. So far I've found four different variants. Time to brush up my VBA

Comment: Based on your additional description, I think the file is saved as key>value pairs for each row. For any particular row, if there is no value for the key then that wouldn't be displayed, hence seemingly different csv files. So either write your own parser or see if there is some kind of xml style sheet that could be used to help with the parsing.

Comment: It can certainly be done within Power Query. I don't know if it would be any more "elegant" than doing it in VBA or Python. Obviously, the specifics depend on what you want as a final result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the only differences are that some rows do not contain all of the `key=value` pairs, then it is relatively easy to handle that in Power Query.

Given this `csv`:

```
"itime=1682240966","date=""2023-04-23""","time=""18:39:26""","devid=""FG101FTK21000840""","vd=""root""","type=""traffic""","subtype=""forward"""
"itime=1682240960","date=""2023-04-23""","time=""18:39:20""","devid=""FG101FTK21000840""","vd=""root""","type=""traffic""","subtype=""forward"""
"itime=1682240966","date=""2023-04-23""","time=""18:40:26""","vd=""root""","type=""traffic""","subtype=""forward"""
"itime=1682240960","date=""2023-04-23""","time=""18:10:20""","devid=""FG101FTK21000840""","type=""traffic""","subtype=""forward"""
```

Read the code comments and examine the Applied Steps to understand the algorithm.

```
let

//change next line to reflect your actual csv document
    Source = Csv.Document(File.Contents("C:\Users\ron\Desktop\New Text Document.txt"),[Delimiter=",", Columns=7, Encoding=1252, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.None]),

//add an index column representing the row number
    #"Add Row Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(Source,"Row",0,1,Int64.Type),

//unpivot columns other than the Row column to => a three column table
  //Remove the Attribute column (which would be the column headers
  //And any rows with no key=value pairs
    #"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Add Row Index", {"Row"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Unpivoted Other Columns", each ([Value] <> "")),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Filtered Rows",{"Attribute"}),

//Add a custom column consisting of only the "Key" portion of the pair
    #"Add Key Column" = Table.AddColumn(#"Removed Columns", "Key", each Text.Split([Value],"="){0}, type text),

//Create a list of the eventual Column Names
    #"Col Names" = List.Distinct(#"Add Key Column"[Key]),

//Group by Row
//then Pivot each subtable
// will => error if any Key=Value pair is duplicated
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Add Key Column", {"Row"}, {
        {"Pivot", (t)=>Table.Pivot(t, #"Col Names","Key", "Value")}}),

//Remove now unneeded Row column and expand the Pivoted tables
    #"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Grouped Rows",{"Row"}),
    #"Expanded Pivot" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Columns1", "Pivot", #"Col Names" ),
    #"Set Data Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Expanded Pivot", List.Transform(#"Col Names", each {_, type text}))
in
    #"Set Data Type"
```

***Results***
[image]

Comment: That does the heavy lifting perfectly, I just need to add the extract and data types. Just one thing I want to check - the Columns attribute in Source, are there any issues with using a number larger than the actual column count? the full output files seem to have anything between 85 and 93 columns, Setting it to 95 doesn't seem to cause a problem...